# I need help with Android and Java

Tags: java, android

I am struggling to figure out how to handle a situation in Android where code continues to execute when I really don't want it to. In the onCreate() of an activity I have some stuff that I need to do in order and I can't have the code continue to execute until certain things happen first. I understand that this is how Android and Java behave and I am struggling to figure out another way to accomplish what I need.

ShowEula is a class that I created to show a simple dialog with my EULA. I really need to wait until the user agrees or disagrees with the EULA before calling DBGetOnlineVersionNumber(). Maybe I'm just not going this the correct way. Anyway here's a snippet of my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String version;
    ShowEula();     
    version = DBGetOnlineVersionNumber();
    ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rethink things in terms of the event-driven model used by android.

You cannot wait for UI events in onCreate, because no UI events can be delivered until after onCreate has returned.

Perhaps you could organize things as a software state machine.

onCreate would show the EULA and set the state to EULA_SHOWING

accept would advance the state to EULA_ACCEPTED and display something next

Of course you probably don't want to show the EULA on every startup, but only after install, but you can handle this with something stored in settings.

Comment: I am using sharedpreferences to handle the EULA. I was thinking what you are suggesting but I am having trouble sorting that all out. Are you suggesting something like handlers? I could set a state for EULA_SHOWING? How would you suggest I do that?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you need to rethink your whole concept of user interface programming to be event-driven.  Both the system and the user will send you events, for things like creation or touch, each time you get an event you do something very quickly and return, possibly setting a state variable so that you know what event you need next/what to do after you get it.

Comment: Chris, I stumbled upon this and am wondering if this might be a better solution. What do you think? SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a issue in general with all GUIs that do things asynchronously. What I normally do is put a boolean in a shared preference and then create two branches in the startup...

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String version;

    if (Settings.isEulaBeenShown() == false) {
        /* showEula would call stuffToDoIfUserAgreesToEULA on a positive response was given */
        ShowEula();
    }
    else if (Settings.isEULAAgreed() == true) {   
        stuffToDoIfUserAgreesToEULA()
    }
    ....
 }

 private void stuffToDoIfUserAgreesToEULA() {
     String version = DBGetOnlineVersionNumber();
 }
```

Comment: Ok, let me tinker a bit and see how that goes. This makes sense and I like the idea of using shared prefs to handle to flags.

Comment: Andrew quick question. Disclaimer: I'm a Android newbie... How would ShowEula call stuffToDoIfUserAgreesToEULA from the Eula class that I created?

Comment: Andrew, thanks a bunch for the help. I think I've got it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create 2 xml layouts.

One for your EULA and the Accept/Deny buttons, and then another for your main app.

When the app loads you can just show the EULA layout if it's the first time and not tracked in the shared preferences.

Then when the user accepts have it setContentView on the application content view.

Abstract out most of your stuff from onCreate() so you can re-use the components, e.g.

```
private static boolean EulaRequired = true;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    EulaRequired = sharedprefs.getBoolean("firsttime", true); 
    inflateLayout();    
 }

 private void inflateLayout() {
   if (EulaRequired) {
     this.setContentView(R.layout.eula);
   } else {
     this.setContentView(R.layout.application);
     DBGetOnlineVersionNumber();
   }
 }
 private void stuffToDoIfUserAgreesToEULA() {
     String version = DBGetOnlineVersionNumber();
 }
 void AcceptClicked(Event e) {
   EulaRequired = false;
   inflateLayout();
 }
```

Something like this should work, I have never tried it though.